Are $\mathcal{F}_U$ and $\mathcal{F}_Y$ quasi-coherent?
If $X$ is a noetherian scheme, and $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on it, then for an open set $U$ and a closed set $Y$, are $\mathcal{F}_U = j_!(\mathcal{F}|_U)$ and $\mathcal{F}_Y = i_*(\mathcal{F}|_Y)$ also quasi-coherent? This question arises from this Proof attempt of exercise 3.2, Ch. III Hartshorne, but I doubt it because in the first case $j_!$ doesn't preserve quasi-coherence, and in the second case $i^{-1}$ doesn't.

They are not in general. For an example, let $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_X$ and suppose $\mathcal{F}_U$ is quasi-coherent. Then since $\mathcal{F}_U$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$, it must be coherent which implies its support is closed (see II, Ex. 5.6 in Hartshorne). But the support of $\mathcal{F}_U$ is U, a contradiction.
Now consider the short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_U \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}_Y \rightarrow 0 $$
where $Y = X \setminus U$. If $\mathcal{F}_Y$ were quasi-coherent, then $\mathcal{F}_U$ would be as well. Therefore $\mathcal{F}_Y$ is not quasi-coherent.

Welcome to MSE! Is that short exact sequence correct? I mean, if $F=\mathcal O_X$, then $F_Y=i_\mathcal O_Y$ and the kernel of $\mathcal O_X\to i_\mathcal O_Y$ is the ideal sheaf of $Y$, which is quasi-coherent?

Thanks for the welcome! Based on the users question, when they write $\mathcal{F}_{|Y}$, I believe they are referring to the sheaf $i^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ where $i: Z \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion and not the sheaf $i^* \mathcal{F}$ that you are referring to. The short exact sequence I use comes from Ex. 1.19 (c) in chapter II of Hartshorne.
